# How to Change Navbar Component Link Buttons Based on User being Logged in or Logged out using JavaScript and React JSX

Tags: react-hooks, jsx

I am trying to have the navigation component in React change from Login to Logout after the user logs in to their profile page.

I am loading the pages in my localhost while in development. The user can already log in successfully. I have tried importing the loggedIn method from my auth.js file in my utils folder on the client side. I then placed a conditional of if logged in then render the Logout link else render the Login and Sign Up link/button. VScode is giving me errors once I place the else conditional in the JSX. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code for my Navigation.js Component:

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import { Container, Nav, Navbar, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import siteLogo from "../../assets/images/logo.png";
import loggedIn from '../../utils/auth';

function Navigation() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar
        bg="dark"
        variant="dark"
        sticky="top"
        expand="sm"
        collapseOnSelect
      >
        <Container>
          <Navbar.Brand>
            <Nav.Link href="/">
              <img alt="" src={siteLogo} className="site-logo"></img>
            </Nav.Link>
          </Navbar.Brand>

          <Navbar.Toggle />
          <Navbar.Collapse>
            <Nav className="me-auto">
              <Nav.Link href="/">Home</Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link href="/about">About</Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link href="/contact">Contact</Nav.Link>
            </Nav>
            <Nav>
              
              {{if:loggedIn}}
              <Nav.Link href="/">Logout</Nav.Link>
              
              {{else}}
              <Nav.Link href="/signin">Login</Nav.Link>
              <Button href="/signup" className="mx-2" variant="primary">
                Sign up
              </Button>
            </Nav>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Container>
      </Navbar>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Navigation;
```

Here is the code for my Auth.js utils:

```
import decode from 'jwt-decode';

class AuthService {
  getProfile() {
    return decode(this.getToken());
  }

  loggedIn() {
    // Checks if there is a saved token and it's still valid
    const token = this.getToken();
    return !!token && !this.isTokenExpired(token); // handwaiving here
  }

  isTokenExpired(token) {
    try {
      const decoded = decode(token);
      if (decoded.exp < Date.now() / 1000) {
        return true;
      } else return false;
    } catch (err) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  getToken() {
    // Retrieves the user token from localStorage
    return localStorage.getItem('id_token');
  }

  login(idToken) {
    // Saves user token to localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('id_token', idToken);

    window.location.assign('/Profile');
  }

  logout() {
    // Clear user token and profile data from localStorage
    // axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = null;
    localStorage.removeItem('id_token');
    // this will reload the page and reset the state of the application
    window.location.assign('/');
  }
}

export default new AuthService();
```

Here is a screenshot of the navigation after the user has already logged in:
[image]

I'm still working on the profile page itself, so please ignore the white space.

Answer (score 0):

you can use conditional rendering, [Here](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) you can find the documentation